# A problem on fair "dice" with $2n$ sides

Tags: probability

Suppose that we have a fair "dice" with $2n$ sides, with sides labeled with numbers $1,...,2n$ and that we do the following:

1) We throw a dice and if a dice lands on odd number we erase that odd number and write some even instead and if a dice lands on even number we erase that even number and write some odd number instead.

2) We throw dice again and repeat 1) until all numbers on a dice are even or until all are odd.

I would like to know what is the expected number of throwings (as a function of $n$) such that a probability of getting all numbers even or all numbers odd is $P(n)\geq \frac {1}{2}$

I know only basics of elementary probability theory so am not, at this moment, able to solve this problem that I conceived a few hours ago.

Is there some more or less elementary approach?

Comment: The probability of getting all evens at the end of the procedure is $1/2$; the probability of getting all odds is $1/2$. Are you asking for the expected number of throws needed to complete the procedure?

Comment: You might be interested in [Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).

Comment: When you have just one of them, it is a die, not a dice.

Comment: "The expected number of throws such that the probability of getting all numbers even or all numbers odd is $P(n)\ge\frac12$" makes no sense. The number of throws needed to make that probability at least $\frac12$ is a deterministic quantity, not a random variable, so it doesn't make sense to ask for its expectation.

Answer (score 1):

You have a Markov chain.  For a given $n$ we can define the expected number of throws to get to all even or all odd when you start with $m$ even as $E(m)$.  By symmetry, $E(m)=E(2n-m)$.  When you throw the die with $m$ even you have $\frac m{2n}$ chance of getting an even number and moving to $m-1$ and $\frac {2n-m}{2n}$ chance of getting an odd number and moving to $m+1$.  This means 
$$E(m)=1+\frac m{2n}E(m-1)+\frac {2n-m}{2n}E(m+1)$$
Coupled with $E(0)=E(2n)=0$ this is $2n-1$ equations in $2n-1$ variables.  The symmetry reduces it to $n$ equations in $n$ variables.

I suspect they grow rapidly because you are so unlikely to make the final step.  For $n=5$ I find $E(1)=511,E(5)=584\frac 13$

Comment: But the question doesn't ask for the expected number of throws to get all even or all odd.

Comment: @joriki:  yes, but as you pointed out the question as stated does not make sense.  I thought this would be useful to OP.